# How to update data from Firestore in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to use update method in FirebaseFirestore instance but it is not working.
I have intialized id as String i.e String Id in the stateful widget

**This is ViewData Page which has a button Widget**

```
class ViewData extends StatefulWidget {
  const ViewData({Key? key, required this.document, required this.id})
      : super(key: key);

  final Map<String, dynamic> document;
  final String id;
```

```
Widget button() {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("mytask").doc(widget.id).update({
          "title": titleController.text,
          "description": descriptionController.text,
          "type": type,
          "category": category,
          "format": format,
        });
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
      child: Container(
        height: 56,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
        ),
        child: const Center(
          child: Text(
            "Update",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 18,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**There is another page named Homepage where Snapshot has been written.**

```
 return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    Map<String, dynamic> document = snapshot.data.docs[index]
                        .data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                    return InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (builder) =>
                                    ViewData(
                                      document: document,
                                      id : snapshot.data.docs[index].id,
                                    ),
                            ),
                        );
                      },
```

***Help me find the correct document id.***

Comment: Update is only for one field. Check : https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/samples/firestore-data-set-field

Comment: How to update multiple field then?

Comment: Check that widget.id is the correct document id.

Comment: I'm a beginner in flutter, can you help find it from the above codes. I have added all the codes wherever snapshot has been mentioned.

Comment: Yeah sure. What i meant is in the inkwell tap function can you print(widget.id) and check whether that id is the valid id in firestore database document.

Comment: No, it's not getting printed.

Comment: Yeah, that's why it's not updating...In the ViewData Screen can you able to view the data? If yes in parsing data from HomePage change id: document.documentID

Comment: use this ` id: snapshot.data[index].documentID `

Comment: I'm getting this error :

Class '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot' has no instance getter 'documentID'.
Receiver: Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot'
Tried calling: documentID

Comment: And yes, i'm able to view data from Homepage

Comment: try using the snapshot type and check the id is getting I've added the code in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add "SetOptions(merge: true)" as below.

```
  Future<void> setData({
    required String path,
    required Map<String, dynamic> data,
  }) async {
    final reference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc(path);
    return reference
        .set(data, SetOptions(merge: true))
        .timeout(const Duration(seconds: timeOutSecond))
        .catchError((onError) {
      if (onError is SocketException) {
        throw Failure(
          exception: onError,
          message: "No internet connection",
          code: onError.message,
        );
      } else if (onError is TimeoutException) {
        throw Failure(
          exception: onError,
          message: "Timeout...",
          code: onError.message,
        );
      } else {
        throw Failure(
          exception: onError,
          message: "An undefined Error happened.",
        );
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `set()` method if you want change many data in doc, `set` will create new document if not exists or overwrite new data in document

```
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("mytask").doc(widget.id).set({
          "title": titleController.text,
          "description": descriptionController.text,
          "type": type,
          "category": category,
          "format": format,
        });
```

See more [how to add data to cloud firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document)

Comment: It's still not working. I'm a beginner in Flutter. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below code by using the snapshot type

```
builder: (BuildContext context,
                            AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasData &&
                              snapshot.data.docs.length != 0) {
                            List<DocumentSnapshot> snap =
                                snapshot.data.docs;
    return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    Map<String, dynamic> document = snapshot.data.docs[index]
                        .data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                    return InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (builder) =>
                                    ViewData(
                                      document: document,
                                      id : snap[index].id,
                                    ),
                            ),
                        );
                      },
    }
```